# Query to find all views/charts owned or shared with a user in Dynamics 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to see all views / charts owned or shared with a user in Dynamics 2013? (DB query would be fine. I can access the base tables if needed.

Answer (score 2):

@Ryan 's solution helped me quite a bit but was painful to transcribe. This is the solution in a more usable format (with minor edits):

```
DECLARE @userid varchar(100)
SELECT @userid = 'domain\user'

-- Get team membership for the user
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#UserAndTeams') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #UserAndTeams

SELECT DISTINCT t.TeamId TeamOrUserId, t.[Name]
INTO #UserAndTeams
FROM
 TeamBase t
  INNER JOIN TeamMembership tm ON t.TeamId = tm.TeamId
  INNER JOIN SystemUserBase su ON su.SystemUserId = tm.SystemUserId
WHERE
 su.DomainName = @userid

INSERT INTO #UserAndTeams(TeamOrUserId, [Name])
SELECT su.SystemUserId, su.Firstname + ' ' + su.Lastname [Name]
FROM SystemUserBase su WHERE su.DomainName = @userid

-- Get a union of all teams and this user
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#AllUsersAndTeams') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AllUsersAndTeams

SELECT t.TeamId TeamOrUserId, t.[Name] 
INTO #AllUsersAndTeams
FROM TeamBase t

INSERT INTO #AllUsersAndTeams(TeamOrUserId, [Name])
SELECT su.SystemUserId, su.Firstname + ' ' + su.Lastname [Name]
FROM SystemUserBase su

-- Extract share info from POA for selected entity types
SELECT DISTINCT su.[Name] SharedWith, objectIds.[Type], objectIds.[Name] Objectname, aut.[Name] Ownername
FROM
 PrincipalobjectAccess poa WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN #UserAndTeams su WITH (NOLOCK) ON poa.PrincipalId = su.TeamOrUserId
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT 'Chart' [Type], UserQueryVisualizationId id, [Name], OwnerId FROM UserQueryVisualizationBase WITH (NOLOCK)
      UNION SELECT 'View', UserQueryId id, [Name], OwnerId FROM UserQueryBase WITH (NOLOCK)
      UNION SELECT 'Report', ReportId, [Name], OwnerId FROM Report WITH (NOLOCK)
      UNION SELECT 'Dashboard', uf.userFormId id, [Name], OwnerId FROM UserForm uf WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE uf.[Type] = 0
    ) objectIds ON poa.ObjectId = objectIds.id
  INNER JOIN #AllUsersAndTeams aut ON objectIds.OwnerId = aut.TeamOrUserId
ORDER BY
 objectIds.[Type], objectIds.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this procedure:

[image: GetSharedObjectsStoredProc]

Which works well for views/dashboards and charts. If a user can access an item via team membership the team name is displayed; if it's been shared directly with the user, the users' name is displayed.

It needs to be run for a user with access to the base tables.

(I can't post the full SQL to Stack Overflow! It's containted in the attached image.)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually trickier then you might think - The information about shared views is contained within the principalobjectaccess table in database.

This table contains the object that's being shared, who it's being shared with, and what permissions they have on that object.

The hard part is that the guid that contains the object being shared does not also specify what object type is being shared as well. It might be possible to create a query that joins the POA table to the views created, and then put in a where clause for that particular user... but be careful and don't run this against a production system (and if you have to make sure to use a (nolock) on the POA table.)

Sorry I couldn't be more help, but I'm not using On-prem and cant test a query.

Comment: The POA table does include the target object type in the "ObjectTypeCode" column.
But POA is only relevant to the sharing of views, not finding out who the original owner is